# Enabling XEP-0198 in aSmack

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I'm currently using asmack against an XMPP server which has XEP-0198 enabled.

I'm trying to enable this feature from the asmack library but I could not find any info on how to do this, so following http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0198.html I know I have to enable this feature by sending:

```
<enable xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/>
```

But I have no idea on how to do this, since this is not a stanza. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
As dant3 has pointed out XEP-0198 is not supported in Smack but I still want to enable it by sending that simple XML through Smack, I just have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like smack [do not have XEP-0198 implementation](http://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/SMACK-333). So, you can't enable it.

It would be nice if you contribute it for smack (and thus - for asmack).

**EDIT:**

Smack 4.1.0 having now support of XEP-0198 stream management. See this [wiki page](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/wiki/Smack-4.1-Readme-and-Upgrade-Guide) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the reality check. Even if it's not supported there must be a way to send that XML to effectively enable it, right?

Comment: Yes, but I can't see how it helps you to implement XEP-0198. And parsing such stanzas with smack will require you to fork as it stands now.

Comment: Smack 4.1.0 having now support of XEP-0198 stream management .
https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/wiki/Smack-4.1-Readme-and-Upgrade-Guide

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I updated the post accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by creating my own type of Package:

```
public class MyPacket extends Packet
{
    private String content = "";

    public MyPacket(String content)
    {
        this.content = content;
    }
    @Override
    public String toXML()
    {
        return this.content;
    }
}
```

I pass the xml in the constructor and then off it goes:

```
MyPacket p = new MyPacket("<enable xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/>");
this.connection.sendPacket(p);
```

Definitely not the best code in the world but it works.

Comment: I don't think thats enough to actually use features of XEP-0198.

Comment: It isn't and I actually found out it's not possible to work your way around smack to use XEP-0198 unless I modify the core library. I was able to enable it like this though!

Comment: Did you found anything else ?